# Get data from $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to create simple server side validation, this is my method

```
public function create() {
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        session_start();
        unset($_SESSION['errors']);

        $count = $this->model->checkIfUserExists($name);
        if($count > 0) {       
            $_SESSION['errors'] = array(
                'message'   => 'User Already Exists',
                'variables' => array(
                    'name'     => $_POST['name'],
                    'password' => $_POST['password'],
                ),
            );  

            header('location: ' . URL . 'user/registration');
            exit;
        }           

        $data = array();
        $data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
        $this->model->create($data);            
        header('location: ' . URL);
    }
```

and below code from **registration.php**

```
<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['errors']) && count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0) {

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($_SESSION['errors'] as $error) {
    echo '<li>' . $error['message'] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
?>
```

but I got errors

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'message' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\views\user\registration.php on line 6
�

Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\views\user\registration.php on line 6
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you try a var_dump of your `$_SESSION['errors']` ?

Comment: Yes, I did it, `var_dump($_SESSION['errors']);` works. Result: `array(2) { ["message"]=> string(19) "User Already Exists" ["variables"]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Admin" ["password"]=> string(5) "admin" } }`

Comment: on both file please write `session_start();` at the top of the page just after `<?php` and then check once

Comment: It's because foreach goes throught items in main array. You should assign $_SESSION['errors']  like $_SESSION['errors'] [] = array( ...

Answer (score 5):

Generally, `Warning: Illegal string offset ...` means that you are trying to **access a string as an array**.

Currently, you are setting `$_SESSION['errors']` to an associative array with two elements, `message` and `variables`. I believe what you are trying to achieve is to create an array with multiple errors that each have a `message` and `variables`.

Setting it like this should do:

```
...

$_SESSION['errors'] = array();

if ($count > 0) {
    $_SESSION['errors'][] = array(
        'message' = > 'User Already Exists',
        'variables' = > array(
            'name' = > $_POST['name'],
            'password' = > $_POST['password'],
        ),
    );

    header('location: '.URL.'user/registration');
    exit;
}

...
```

The empty square brackets add a new element to the array:

```
$myArray[] = $myNewElement;
```

This way you can easily **add additional errors** to the list:

```
$_SESSION['errors'][] = array(
    'message' = > 'Error two',
    'variables' = > array(...),
);
$_SESSION['errors'][] = array(
    'message' = > 'Error three',
    'variables' = > array(...),
);
```

Comment: Could you please explain me how to create array with different errors for different cases? I would like to add couple other validations in my method, but I don't understand how to collect different errors and then display them on page.

Comment: I added it to the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: How can I add different names for different errors and get them on the page?

Comment: Well, you can use an **associative array**. This allows you to use strings as keys instead of the numeric index. Finding a guide on Google should be easy. You can also have a look at the [PHP docs for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's because foreach goes throught items in main array. ["message", "variables"]

Assign `$_SESSION['errors'] =` like this: `$_SESSION['errors'][] =`

```
$_SESSION['errors'][] = array(
                    'message'   => 'User Already Exists',
                    'variables' => array(
                        'name'     => $_POST['name'],
                        'password' => $_POST['password'],
                    ),
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

**registration.php** at first start session `session_start()`

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['errors']) && count($_SESSION['errors']) > 0) {

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($_SESSION['errors'] as $error) {
    echo '<li>' . $error['message'] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
unset($_SESSION['errors']);
}
?>
```

Comment: I've already added `session_start()` in my **header.php** file

Comment: Start individual page.

Comment: I get error `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\views\user\registration.php on line 2`